# Intellij macros stop working after a couple of times

Tags: intellij-idea, macros

I'm working on IntellijUltimate-2019.2 but have seen this issue on previous versions as well. When I try to create a macro and replay it, it works fine one or two times, but starts doing something else next time onward.

I do have some custom shortcuts setup and I'm running Intellij over RDP. My local system is Ubuntu and RDPing using Remmina.

Has anyone faced similar issues before or have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the exact steps to reproduce and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) attached.

Comment: Thanks. I think I figured out what was wrong while reporting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly one, but posting a response here (instead of deleting this post) in case anyone else is running into the same issue.

If you are using a combination of keys to trigger a macro (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>), make sure to leave the first key immediately after pressing the second key, else they will interfere the macro replay.

I was using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to trigger the macro. The macro included typing "P", but because I wasn't letting go <kbd>Alt</kbd> fast enough, instead of typing "P", it was triggering another action that I had mapped against <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.